# Iterate through a list of objects in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have code like this:

```
class Canine
  constructor: (@breed) ->
  whichBreed: ->
    alert @breed

poodle = new Canine "poodle"
labrador = new Canine "labrador"

iterate = ->
  poodle.whichBreed()
  labrador.whichBreed()
```

What I want is something like this:

```
listOfDogs = [poodle, labrador]
for d in listOfDogs
  d.whichBreed()
```

but it doesn't work that way. **Is it possible to iterate through a list of objects with the same structure?**

Comment: I tried your code and it works...

Comment: When I call `poodle.whichBreed()` and `labrador.whichBreed()` in the way indicated above, my code does something different than when I do it by `d.whichBreed()` in the loop (in the latter case, the functions in my actual code don't get called -- changing from individual calls to looping being the only difference). Thinking about it, everything is an object in JS so of course you can iterate over a list of coffeescript objects. It was 3AM when I asked this question, sorry. I'm going to ask a new, better one if I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Syzygy I'd be surprised if you could replicate this. `d.whichBreed() for d in [poodle, labrador]` should be absolutely equivalent to `poodle.whichBreed(); labrador.whichBreed()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
class Canine
  constructor: (@breed) ->
  whichBreed: ->
    alert @breed

poodle = new Canine "poodle"
labrador = new Canine "labrador"

iterate = ->
  poodle.whichBreed()
  labrador.whichBreed()

listOfDogs = [poodle, labrador]
for d in listOfDogs
  d.whichBreed()
```

(changing `new Animal` to `new Canine`)? Because that works fine... I get the expected output

```
poodle
labrador
```

Comment: Something else is wrong with my code, see comment above for more info if interested. Thanks!